# How to add a New Action when viewing a Custom Perspective in OmniFocus 3?

Tags: omnifocus

I have created a custom perspective in OmniFocus 3.11.2 for macOS. How do I add a New Action when viewing this perspective? Trying several approaches, I always just get an audible signal and nothing else happens.

Strategies that produce this:

- menu bar File -> New Action
- the keystroke shortcut for File -> New Action
- the Return key

No combination of grouping or sorting has enabled me to add a New Action.

Background: my custom perspective filter rules only show actions that are

- Available
- In an active project
- Contained within a few projects or folders

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add a new action while viewing a custom perspective, as it's not possible to know where to put the action. Perspectives can combine projects, tags, etc., so there's no simple destination for the new action.

To create a new action from anywhere including a custom perspective, use [Quick Entry](https://support.omnigroup.com/documentation/omnifocus/mac/3.0/en/capture-methods/#quick-entry).